# How can I solve this compiler error when trying to execute an xchg command in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm writing a semaphore and I need to run the following command:

```
xchg rax, [rdi]
```

However, the compiler tells me that this line produces the error "impossible combination of address sizes"

Makes sense, I tell to myself, since the thing on the right hand is a byte and rax is a dword

So I write the following, that should fix it:

```
xchg rax, qword [rdi]
```

But it throws the same error

Isn't rax a 64-byte register? Why is it throwing this error then?

Comment: Are you sure that's the line containing the error? Both versions are correct and nasm accepts them without problems.

Comment: a million percent sure. I can paste the whole code if you'd like

Comment: I just realized it's probably some error in my compile flags.

Comment: Yeah if you tried to assemble as 32 bit then you'd get that error.

Comment: You generally don't need a whole qword for a semaphore.  A dword is fine, or even a byte depending on what kind of semaphore it is.  BTW, NASM doesn't have any magic association between labels and operand-sizes the way MASM does.  And not even MASM would that RDI was a `uint8_t *` instead of `uint64_t*`.  So no, the thing on the right hand side isn't "a byte", it's "a memory operand with qword size implied by the other operand".

Comment: duplicate of [impossible combination of address sizes and invalid effective address on simple operation](//stackoverflow.com/q/49713512)  (Forgot to search for dupes before using my close-vote on "typographic error" / trivial problem;  but in retrospect it is useful for wrong BITS setting to come up as an explanation in a google search for `nasm "impossible combination of address sizes"`)